# Excel Query from Sharepoint List with more ids than the existing

Tags: sharepoint-online

lately my sharepoint its going nuts, its duplicating information when i copy data directly to the sharepoint manually.

As you can see in this picture the sharepoint list, for this person, starts on the id 1369

[image]

And you can see in the image below that my sharepoint dont have the id 1368

[image]

But the excel (query) i extract from the sharepoint list i have the 1368. It copies the line of 1369 entirely... so i have repeted item.

[image]

So:

1. How is this possible?
2. how can i delete the extra id?
3. how can i avoid this to happen?

thank you for your help